# passing parameter to a lambda function from dataframe.groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a data fram like this named rest,

```
                AAPL     MSFT    XOM    SPX
  2003-01-02    7.40    21.11   29.22   909.03
  2003-01-03    7.45    21.14   29.24   908.59
  2003-01-06    7.45    21.52   29.96   929.01
  2003-01-07    7.43    21.93   28.95   922.93
  2003-01-08    7.28    21.31   28.83   909.93
```

If I run this code, it executes, but what I am not getting is what we are getting in the lambda function( x is a dataframe rest or the index column) because if x is dataframe then x.year shouldn't execute, right?

```
spx=lambda x:x.corrwith(x['SPX'])
get_year=lambda x:x.year
by_year=rest.groupby(get_year)
by_year.apply(spx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on the index, so `x` passed to the `get_year` lambda is `rest.index`, and `x.year` is `rest.index.year`, which is well defined.

Here's the [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) documentation reference:

> DataFrame.groupby(**by**=None, axis=0, level=None, as_index=True, sort=True, group_keys=True, squeeze=, observed=False, dropna=True)[source]
>
> ...
>
> If **by** is a function, it’s called on each value of the object’s index